# changing ringtone with tts in android

Tags: android, android-intent, text-to-speech

I m trying to make an app in which when a incoming call comes identify the number and by using android text to speech it ll say the contact name of caller. i had done almost my problem is when call comes instead of default ring tone it should say the TTS.how to override ringtone with TTS
here i m giving what i tried. can any one help me to get a better solution. i had tried the first answer now the ring volume got muted. but tts sound not coming.

```
   public class myPhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    int ph_state = 0;
    speechcontact clsspcntct = new speechcontact();
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
        {

            String phoneNumber =   incomingNumber;
            String ContactName = objUtility.getContactName2(context,phoneNumber);

            if (RBSpkMde.isChecked())
            {
                speakWords(ContactName);
            }
        } 
    }
     public void speakWords(String speech)
    {
    myTTS.speak("you have call from"+speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mute the `STREAM_RING`

```
public class myPhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    private int mRingVolume;
    Context context;

    public myPhoneStateChangeListener(Context cxt)
    {
        context = cxt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
        {
            mRingVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
            String phoneNumber =   incomingNumber;
            String ContactName = objUtility.getContactName2(context,phoneNumber);

            if (RBSpkMde.isChecked())
            {
                speakWords(ContactName);
            }
        } 
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
             mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
             mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 
                        mRingVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);
        }
    }
     public void speakWords(String speech)
    {
    myTTS.speak("you have call from"+speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }

}
```

Comment: where should i apply this?

Comment: inside if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING). So just put the first two line right after the if statement. And if you want the phone to revert to normal ringing after tts speech then onUtteranceCompleted you put the last two lines. If not then put it on CALL_STATE_IDLE

Comment: what is the datatype of mRingVolume?

Comment: what about this line  mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 
                           mPhoneStateListener.ringVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES);  i'm getting error in this line  mPhoneStateListener.ringVolume

Comment: I edited my answer, I did not have it on IDLE in my code and I just cut and paste.

Comment: @HoanNguyen If you add required fields too in the above answer it is very great answer from you..

Comment: @JesbinMJ Have you got this answer? If so then finish this answer with including all fields with data types.. so that it can be helpful for all who facing problem like this..

Comment: @HoanNguyen Add these fields `mRingVolume`, `mAudioManager`, `context` and where is `objUtility` post that code also..

Comment: @shylendra I just assume from the question that myPhoneStateChangeListener is an inner class. mAudioManager would be a field member of the outer class instantiate somewhere with mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); and objUtility is what ever JesbinMJ defines it to be. For the other 2 it is reasonable to define in the above class so I modify the answer to reflect it.

Comment: @HoanNguyen Thanks for the response, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: @HoanNguyen where can I use this line `mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);` in the above code

Comment: @shylendra You can declare private AudioManager mAudioManager as a field member of the class myPhoneStateChangeListener and instantiate the above line in the constructor.